# Getting Media Title from a File

Tags: java, android, file, sdk, mediastore

I used `import java.io.File;` to import all music files from my sdcard,
Now i want the Title's of the files using Mediastore  but how do I do that?
This is the code I Use now.

```
public class ListFiles extends ListActivity {
 private List<String> directoryEntries = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    File directory = new File(i.getStringExtra("directory"));

    if (directory.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                return -Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
            }
        });

        this.directoryEntries.clear();
        for (File file : files) {
            this.directoryEntries.add(file.getName());  
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.file_row, this.directoryEntries);
    this.setListAdapter(directoryList);
    }

}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
File clickedFile = new File(this.directoryEntries.get(position));
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("clickedFile", clickedFile.toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that for Video files using **[MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)** : Class Overview - The Media provider contains **meta data** for all available media on both internal and external storage devices.

You can refer these two example to understand the use of MediaStore
**[List Video](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-video-files-stored.html)** and **[List Audio](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html)**

Comment: can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934159/mediastore-not-working-when-folder-programmatically-created I need help