# access android media directory?

Tags: android, directory, media

ey up. ive built a simple music app that reads wav files from the sdcard and plays them.
how do i access the default media directory?
this is how i get the sdcard

```
public void LoadSounds() throws IOException
    {
        String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

         if(!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
             //handle error here
         }
         else {

         File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()); //this needs to be a folder the user can access, like media
```

as usual the docs dont give an actual example of usage but it says this - If you're using API Level 8 or greater, use getExternalFilesDir() to open a File that represents the external storage directory where you should save your files. This method takes a type parameter that specifies the type of subdirectory you want, such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC...

how do i use it?
thank you

edit:
this makes it crash if i try to fill a spinner array with file path Strings.

```
File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            File sd = new File(path, "/myFolder");

File[] sdDirList = sd.listFiles(new WavFilter()); 
         if (sdDirList != null)
         {   
             //sort the spinner 
            amountofiles = sdDirList.length;


             array_spinner=new String[amountofiles];
......
final Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); //crashes here

        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, array_spinner);
```

EDIT2:
ok so ive done this test that is supposed to write a txt file to the music directory.
i run the app, no txt file is written anywhere on the device i can find.

```
 // Path to write files to
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();

        String fname = "mytest.txt";

        // Current state of the external media
        String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        // External media can be written onto
        if (extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            try {
                // Make sure the path exists
                boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
                if (!exists){ new File(path).mkdirs(); }  

                // Open output stream
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + fname);

                fOut.write("Test".getBytes());

                // Close output stream
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }



    }
```

another edit: i will get this working!!
so if i use this line it creates a folder on the sdcard called 'Musictest'. dont understand??

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "test").getAbsolutePath();
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Final Edit:
right so this will look for a folder called test in the devices music directory.
if it doesnt exist, it will be created.
(some fixing to be done here, error if empty) it then lists the files in the directory and adds them to an array.

```
 public void LoadSounds() throws IOException
    {
        String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        // Path to write files to
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/test").getAbsolutePath();

         if(!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
             //handle error here
         }
         else {
             //do your file work here 

                // Make sure the path exists
                boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists(); 
                //if not create it
                if (!exists){ new File(path).mkdirs(); }


         File sd = new File(path);
         //This will return an array with all the Files (directories and files)
         //in the external storage folder

         File[] sdDirList = sd.listFiles(); 

         if (sdDirList != null)
         {   
             //add the files to the spinner array
             array_spinnerLoad=new String[sdDirList.length];
             files = new String[sdDirList.length];

         for(int i=0;i<sdDirList.length;i++){

         array_spinnerLoad[i] = sdDirList[i].getName();
        files[i] = sdDirList[i].getAbsolutePath();
         }

         }
         }
    }
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242342/getting-media-title-from-a-file/8242849#8242849

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as mentioned in the docs, [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) return [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). And File object can represent either file or directory.

Therefore:

```
File musicDirectory = new File( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC));
```

Will give you the object to play with.

Comment: ah spoke too soon, it just crashes, i also had to put a string in there. File sd = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), mysteryString);

Comment: i fill a spinner adapter with the names of the files, it crashes on here. if i use a string for the file (one i know exists sdcard/myfolder) it works.

Comment: hmm... this is beyond what current question is. I think you should created another question about that.

Comment: no its within the scope of the question. im asking how to access the media directory. if i use your original answers code it does not return any files even though i know they are there. if i try to get a known directory (eg. sdcard/myfolder) by a string path it works. in this case im using the fact that it crashed (returned null) as an indication it did not read the media directory. would be the same end result if i used a log to tell me that. it seems Directory_Music does not guarantee access to the folder called Music on a real device.

Comment: sussed it :) ill add the solution to my post, ill give the answer to you since your the only one to try and help

Comment: @user1033558, if no other answer nailed the problem and you found the answer. You should write the answer as *answer* and mark it as the right answer. Don't just update your question. Stackoverflow is about Q/A. Not who asked question and answer it. It's no problem if you found the answer (and actually write it as an answer) to your own question.